# Python with Office365 REST api upload large files to SharePoint using create_upload_session

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint

**Python with Office365 REST api**

I am using the REST api to upload files that are hundreds of MB each.  The code I have works, but I am forced to create a temporary file for each upload.  I have the file in memory already and would love to just send it.  But, the API only seems to support a file handle.  Am I missing something or is there a better way?

```
                file_b_data = io.BytesIO(
                    sp_obj.download_file(ab_zip_file.name, folder.name)
                )
                logger.warning(f"Finished downloading {folder.name}/{ab_zip_file.name}")
                zip_file = ZipFile(file_b_data)

                for z_file in zip_file.filelist:
                    logger.warning(
                        f"Extracting: {folder.name}_{ab_zip_file.name}_{z_file.filename}, Size: {z_file.file_size}"
                    )
                    content = zip_file.read(z_file)
                    upload_fname = z_file.filename

                    if "/" in upload_fname:
                        upload_fname = f'{folder.name}_{upload_fname.partition("/")[2]}'

                    tmp_file = tmp_path.joinpath(upload_fname)
                    logger.debug(f"Uploading File: {tmp_file}")
                    with open(tmp_file, "wb") as f:
                        f.write(content)
                        f.flush()
                        f.close()

                    time.sleep(2)
                    ab_folder.files.create_upload_session(
                        tmp_file,
                        chunk_size=3072000,
                        chunk_uploaded=print_upload_progress,
                    ).execute_query_retry()
```

The purpose for the flush() and sleep(2) are the code is running in multiple threads and the first file will fail to read if it isn't given a few seconds to close up shop.  This is one of the many reasons I want to use a memory buffer instead of a temp file.

Thanks...

I attempted to use an IOBytes buffer, but it is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

After much research I found the answer. It turns out io.BytesIO is supported but you must pass in file_name and file_size as kwargs.  When that happens it doesn't call the fileno().

```
def upload_file(ab_files: FileCollection, content: io.BytesIO | Path, **kwargs):
if isinstance(content, Path):
    upload_name = content.stem + content.suffix
else:
    upload_name = kwargs.get("upload_name")
logger.debug(f"Uploading File: {upload_name}")
fc_session: FileCollection = ab_files.create_upload_session(
    content,
    chunk_size=2048000,
    chunk_uploaded=print_upload_progress,
    print_f_name=upload_name,
    file_name=upload_name,
    file_size=kwargs.get("file_size"),
)
fc_session.execute_query_retry(max_retry=10)
```